# How to create a unique create-react-app project template shared by all other projects keeping everything up to date?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

`create-react-app` helps me get up and running quickly.

Though, I have ejected the created app, did several modifications to it and have created my own project template with all the tools I need to get up and running quickly even more (this includes stuff like i18n, organization of SCSS files, installation of JS/CSS libraries which I use across all projects, reusable React components I have written, utility files, ESLint configuration, TypeScript integration, and so on).

Now that I have this project template created from `create-react-app` I am wondering how I can reuse it/share it across all my other projects.

Currently, assuming `my-modified-create-react-app` is this project template with all the added functionality and modifications I made on top of `create-react-app`, whenever I create a new app (let's say `new-app`), I simply do this:

```
$ cp -R my-modified-create-react-app/. new-app/
```

And then I `cd new-app/` and start building it as if it were a new app using my own well-known tools.

The following things come to my mind:

- If I add further features to my original `my-modified-create-react-app/` template project, how can I easily share the new tools I am adding across all the other already existent projects?

  One solution could be creating an `npm` package for each piece of
  additional functionality and then install them as separate dependencies in each of
  my projects, but in `my-modified-create-react-app/` I also have
  "bootstrap"/"wiring up" code which orchestrates everything and I would like to eventually share/update this code in all my projects easily too.

  Also, running `npx create-react-app` all the time and reinstalling all the common libraries I reuse across all projects everytime is a mundane task too.
- How do I keep `create-react-app`-related stuff up to date? E.g., when the Create React App team publishes an update to `create-react-app`, is it sufficient to run `npm install react-scripts@latest` from `my-modified-create-react-app/` in order update like stated below (on https://create-react-app.dev/)?

  [image]

  Do I need to run it for each of the copied projects or maybe is there an easier way?

How do you handle this guys?

Thank you for the attention.

Answer (score 1):

The key is NOT to eject.

This is the recommended way of extending react app templates until CRA 3.2.0 to AVOID ejecting:
https://auth0.com/blog/how-to-configure-create-react-app/

And the new version of create react app, not yet released will make that even easier as you can read something here for CRA version 3.3.0
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

At this moment, 3.3.0 is in master, not yet released. So is not stable but you can give it a try provided is intended to be released before the end of year.

You can create a cra 3.3.0 project and port your changes.

Depending what you want to share, you can either create templates as git repos, tagged with versions, and you can "FORK" it to have different apps. Then if there is an improvement, the cloned apps can take the advancements pulling from that particular git upstream. @see
https://help.github.com/en/github/getting-started-with-github/fork-a-repo#keep-your-fork-synced

If you want to share react components like , you can put it in a repo, then install it in other projects as node modules from git directly (without passing for a private npm registry), or you can use a public npm registry, or a private one like Artifactory or the one that comes by default with gitLab.

All your templates can still update or not their dependency on react-scripts (CRA), etc. As stated here:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/updating-to-new-releases/

You need to play with npm packages, npm registries, 
git multiple remotes
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes
git tagging, semver/semantic versioning.

You have CRACO https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco
to extend CRA config without ejecting too. I'm not using it at the moment.

Comment: Sounds interesting, gonna give it a try! Thank you!